# Why aren't entities showing up spring-boot-starter-data-rest queries?

Tags: spring-data-rest

Trying to follow the steps in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/, my app launches, curl is able to post an entity, the entity count increments, but unlike the examples in the tutorial, no entities are returned.

Theirs:

[image]

Mine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this, I'd been working in Javascript, which doesn't require "get"/"set" prefixing. Without the prefixes, the framework ignored the fields.